# Making td link using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

my json looks like this:

```
{
    "client": "name", 
    "ip": "ip", 
    "status": "up", 
    "smoke": "smokeping-graph.png"
}
```

I am parsing this info dynamically to make table like this (for the first 3 element):

```
$.getJSON("url/clients.json",
function (data) {

var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].client +  "</td>");
    $('table').append(tr);

   if(data[i].status == "up")
    {
      $('td',tr).css ('background-color', '#88d066');
     } else {
      $('td',tr).addClass("statusHOSTDOWN");
    };
}
});
```

For the fourth element with image link, I want to display it such a way that when you mouse over the table graph image pops up. I have the html version worked out which looks like this:

```
<div class="biz">
<a href="#">PING<span><img src="smokeping-graph.png" /></span></a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.biz a { position:relative !important; }
.biz a span {
        position:absolute !important;
        display:none !important;
        z-index:99 !important;
        }
.biz a:hover span {
        display:block !important;
        border:2px solid gray;
        margin-top: -3px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: white;
        }
.biz {
 margin-top: 400px;
 font-size: 7pt;
 font-family: verdana;
 font-weight: 600;
 color: orangered;
}
```

I am stuck at js logic, so far I came up with this, and its not working like I hoped for:

```
   if(data[i].smoke != "" )
    {
      $('td').attr("href",  data[i].smoke);
      $('td').addClass("link");
    } else {

    };
```

gif for example:

[hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2STbN.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the quickest way to do that, although it's a bit dirty.

```
$.getJSON("url/clients.json",
function (data) {

var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    if(data[i].smoke != "") {
       tr.append('<td><a class="link" href="'+data[i].smoke+'">' + data[i].client +  "</a></td>");
    } else {
       tr.append("<td>" + data[i].client +  "</td>");
    }
    $('table').append(tr);

   if(data[i].status == "up")
    {
      $('td',tr).css ('background-color', '#88d066');
     } else {
      $('td',tr).addClass("statusHOSTDOWN");
    };
}
});
```

Comment: Oh wow, it works exactly how I wanted :). One minor issue that not all of them has image links and those without image links to url/undefined. Would be nice if it could be avoided. Thanks!

Comment: So what is the ".smoke" value of these items then? Is it an empty string, null, ...? Currenty the second line inside the for loop is responible for filtering out the right TDs.

Comment: You are right I should have checked first. Their smoke value wasn't given yet. I removed them for testing and forgot to put them back. Thanks again.